# Cubic equation with cubic

Tags: complex-numbers, cubics

I have a question that I am finding difficult to answer.

$a = 1 + 4i$ satifies the cubic equation:$$z³+5z²+kz+m=0$$
    where $k$ and $m$ are real constants

I believe using $a^2$ and $a^3$ will help to find what $k$ and $m$ and also the other roots of the equation but I am not sure where to go.

Thank you for your help

Comment: If a real polynomial (i.e $ax^n+bx^{n-1}+...=0$) has a complex root $a+bi$, it also has the complex root $a-bi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Expand the cubic $(z-\alpha)(z-1-4i)(z-1+4i)$ and then choose $\alpha$ such that the coefficient of $z^2$ is $5$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint : if $\alpha=1+4i$ is a root (of a real polynomial) then $\beta=1-4i$ is also a root. We also have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-5.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now calculate $(z^2-2z+17)(z-\gamma)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Plug in the root and retrieve the real and imaginary parts and put them to zero :

$$(1+4i)^3+5\,(1+4i)^2+(1+4i)k+m=0$$
$$(k+m-122)+(4k-12)i=0$$

The imaginary part equal to zero gives $k=3$ and this in the real part leads to $m=119$

**Option 2:** You have the root, so you know that $f(z)$ is divisible by $z-1-4i$. By polynomial long-division, you find :

$$z^3+5\,z^2+k\,z+m = (z-1-4\,i)\,(z^2+(6+4\,i)\,z+k - 10 + 28\,i)$$
$$ + (k+m-122)+(4k-12)\,i$$

The remainder of this division should be zero, thus :

$$(k+m-122)+(4k-12)i=0$$